# How can I remove a particular call signature from a Typescript interface with multiple call signatures?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, overloading

## Problem statement

I would like to start with an interface that has many overloaded call signatures, and *replace* one of them with a different signature. This means that I have to *omit* a particular signature from the base interface before adding its replacement.

## Goal

Presume that I start with this interface:

```js
interface Foo {
  (options: {method: 'authorize', userId: number}): Promise<string>;
  (options: {method: 'deauthorize', authToken: string}): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

And I want to *end* with this interface:

```js
interface Bar {
  (options: {method: 'authorize', userToken: string}): Promise<string>; // NEW
  (options: {method: 'deauthorize', authToken: string}): Promise<boolean>; // UNALTERED
}
```

## What I've tried

I tried to use the `Exclude` utility type to remove the unwanted signature.

```js
type BaseInterface = Exclude<Foo, (options: {method: 'authorize', userId: number}) => Promise<string>>;

interface Bar extends BaseInterface {
  (options: {method: 'authorize', userToken: string}): Promise<string>;
}
```

…but that just resulted in `BaseInterface` being of type `never`.

Comment: why do you have to omit a signature first?

Comment: “why do you have to omit a signature first?“ => I believe that I need to omit the original call signature because I don't want to end up with TWO signatures that both feature `{method: 'authorize'}` but with different companion properties.